# Why empty assignment compiled with no errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-4.0, compiler-bug

Here is my snippet:

```
var country = BLLocations.Instance.GetCountries();
ddlCountry.DataSource = 
ddlCountry.DataTextField = "Country";
ddlCountry.DataValueField = "CountryCode";
ddlCountry.DataBind();
```

See the second line:

```
ddlCountry.DataSource =
```

And it compiled successfully and published to cloud also. Strange!

Comment: I'm no C# expert, but I think it's being interpreted as `a = b = "Country";`.

Comment: @Blender Yes you are correct. This error i got DataBinding: 'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name 'Country'.

Comment: I added another `<p>` which you may find useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's simply this:

```
ddlCountry.DataSource =  ddlCountry.DataTextField = "Country";
```

The line break doesn't effect, Which is a valid code.

Just like:

```
var x = 2;
var y = 3;
x = y = 1000;
```

(Note this is really not good practice at all! it's confusing and hard to disgust)

Every code in C# returns a value(though the value can be void) which lets you do this lazy loading:

```
return x ?? x = new ExpensiveObject();//
```

What it does:

1. If x is not null returns x.
2. If x is null assigns x `new ExpensiveObject()` an returns the assignment value - x.

Helpful feature but be careful with it.

Comment: Side-note: doesn't work in VB.NET where  assignments don't return a value.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I added a `<p>` about that, it's really good place to show where it's very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It is acceptable, just like when you can have:

```
a = b = c;
```

I am suprised there isn't a warning though due to types. ddlCountry.DataSource and       ddlCountry.DataTextField would have to be the same type I think.

The compiler ignores white space in this instance as it is syntactically insignificant. More specifically this is done by the pre processor.

Comment: It's because `DataSource` is of type `object` so it'll happily accept any value.

Comment: _"The compiler ignores whitespace."_ isn't true, **it just ignores in this specific case!**

Answer (score 0):

In C#, like with many other languages, statements are separated by `;` characters, *not* by new line characters. Thus writing :

```
var someString =


"SomeValue";
```

Is perfectly fine.

Your snippet does the same as

```
ddlCountry.DataSource = "Country";
ddlCountry.DataTextField = "Country";
```